# How do you include a bower library in angular that does not have app dependency

Tags: angularjs, frontend, bower

I'm trying to use a bower library that does not have a dependency to be added to the AngularJS module.

Typically to include a bower library in angular I would bower install the library and then add that library to my app.js like so

angular.module('myModule', ['bower library']);

However I'm trying to add this bower library https://github.com/Caged/d3-tip which does not have a angular dependency to be injected. So I have nothing to inject into angular.module.

My overall question is how does one get a bower library that does not have an angular dependency to be injected into an angular app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My overall question is how does one get a bower library that does not have an angular dependency to be injected into an angular app?

You don't. If a library is not an Angular module, it cannot be (and does not need to be) injected as a dependency into your Angular module.

The good news is that in most cases, libraries like that can be used globally out-of-the-box. In this case, it looks like that library adds functionality to D3.js. So when you use `d3`, just use `d3.tip()`.